# Inactivate all occurrences of a symbol

Tags: evaluation

I would like to inactivate all occurrences of a symbol to prevent it from evaluating, regardless where in the evaluation process it appears. A minimal example:

```
g[x_] := foo;
f[x_] := x + g[x];
Inactivate[f[2] + g[3], g]
(*== output ==*)
2 + f00 + Inactive[g][3]
```

My desired output would be `2 + Inactive[g][2] + Inactive[g][3]`.

I understand that there would be thorny issues in general how to handle scoping constructs such as `Block` and `Module` but my naïve wish is "inactivate everywhere there is a head `g` and don't care about anything else".

(*Additional comments:* I don't want to write a temporary overwriting definition of `g` as the function of my actual interest has several down values which take quite some time to compute. Something like [the fictitious] `SetAttributes[g,NeverEvaluates]` could be something though.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that this works, your final paragraph notwithstanding as the downvalues of `g` are not lost by using [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html).

```
Block[{g = Inactive[g]}, f[2] + g[3]]
```

> ```
> 2 + Inactive[g][2] + Inactive[g][3]
> ```

Since [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) has [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) infinite recursion does not occur.

Comment: This works as long as `g` is not redefined inside a `Block` inside another definition (like `f[x_]:=Block[{g}, g[y_]:=bar; x + g[x]]`), which is rather contrived indeed. It does work for my purposes so I accept and smile. Thanks!